# Transmission Line Voltage Terminology Confusion (Very Basic)

Tags: voltage, power, transmission-line, power-engineering

I have a issue interpreting what transmission line voltage actually means (I have tried researching but nothing clearly explains in detail, just says its a 110kV line etc).For example if i have a 220kV transmission line, and this transmission line is modeled by short line approximation (hence admittance is negligible), is this 220kV what is being received (for VR). I assume not as then the sending end voltage would be higher than 220KV due to line losses hence i am confused to what this 220kV entails.

Instead is this 220KV essentially like the middle voltage of the line? As in the line wants to have voltage that is around 220KV, thus is it just a guide? However the actual sending end voltage could possibly (most likely) be higher than 220KV and the receiving end voltage be lower than 220kV, i.e. constantly varying based upon the load recieved.

Therefore when a question or someone states "thats a 220kV or thats a 110kV line", is that value essentially what the lines voltage will be maintained around, i.e. it could be higher than 220kV or lower than 220kV but it wants to see pretty much 220kV? Like a middle guide basically for the line?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: 220000 is a big number and there are tolerances, but the nominal voltage is that and everywhere on that line is supposed to be within that tolerance. The voltage drops in real systems are probably smaller than you think.

Comment: So for example if i had chosen to design a 220kV transmission line using short method approximation, how would you choose the receiving voltage? Could you do anything for VR or would you want something close to VR (i.e. you would want something smaller than 220kV due to line losses wouldnt you? Like we want the middle of the line to theoretically be 110kV right? Eg if i used the empirical formula to calculate teh line voltage would this be VR?

Comment: Empirical Formula: https://www.electricaleasy.com/2016/04/economic-choice-of-transmission-voltage.html

Comment: The loss of a 220kV line is maybe 5% not 50% and depends on the load.

Comment: sorry yeah it was a typo of 110kv to actually be 220kV so the recieving end voltage could be 5% of 220kV. Also what do you mean it depends on the load aswell, say for example i need a 50MW load and the transmission line voltage is 220KV at 50kM. Could the recieving end voltage (Line-Line) be anything between 220kV to 209kV?

Comment: If there is no load (and we ignore the transmission line being such) then you input 220kV and since there is no voltage drop (because no current flows) you get out 220kV ... the more current you draw, the higher the I²R losses get, the lower the voltage at the other end becomes.

Comment: Oh ok Thanks, however if i was calculating the sending end voltage using Vs=Vr+ZIr where i can calculate Ir (if i know what to use for Vr, have the power needed etc at the load) and have the impedance, the only issue i have is what value do i select for Vr. Example if the transmission line was 220kV at 50 hz at 10kM. Could i just have Vr as 220kv or do i choose something a little less like 215kV I know these are line to line voltages and to get Vr its Vl-l/sqrt3